# In what direction should Graph relationships point?

Tags: graph-theory

When building out a graph with vertices and edges, and each edge is directional with a single source and target, should the relationship:

1)  Have the parent as source and point to the child
2)  Point upstream towards the parent?

At this stage I can't think of a reason why either would be better in my project, but I'm not certain if I'll run into complexities later on...

According to Graph Theory, does it even matter?
If it doesn't, is there a standard way everyone should do it just for uniformity?

Comment: is this really a graph or a tree? parent-child relationships are usually in trees. of course, a tree can be seen as a graph, but...

Comment: @Aksakal There are elements of both.  There is structural inheritance that looks like a tree (so here I need explicit parent relationships), but then nodes will have properties (nodes) which will be shared across the graph

Comment: Inheritance relationships usually point to a parent, like in UML subtype -> type, e.g. see https://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams/class-multiple-inheritance.png . the reason is that your parent doesn't keep count of children, it's the children that know their parents.